# How to add all columns of a table to a report at once

Tags: powerbi-desktop

I've recently started using Power BI Desktop. There are some tables with 100+ columns that I want to pull into reports. Currently I'm selecting every column/field one by one. Editing query seem to only edit the source I got for the table. Is there a way to select and add all columns of a table at once?

Would also be helpful if I could stop the refresh every time I add a columns. It starts being really slow after a point to add new columns.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe a case of wrong tool for the job? Why would you ever want to build a visual with over 100 columns in a table? What kind of insight would that provide for the end user? That's a horrible user experience. Power BI reports are for visualizing data. What you describe seems like a data dump. Why not just look at the source table directly?

Comment: yes, definitely not the right tool for what we need. I'm using it to connect to a spark instance to pull some data from a database otherwise I have no other way to connect atm.

Comment: So, why don't you just look at the table?? Do you need it in a report in the browser?? And, if you can get it in Power BI, you can also get it in Excel, so, why not build the query in Excel? THAT was made to handle hundreds of columns.

Comment: hey, sorry for very late response. Can't find a driver for spark in Excel.